# How can I create a Segue from my SKScene to another UIViewController?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, segue

I am currently making a very basic "Pong" game. I have the application running, but I want to add a gameover screen. Once the either the user or computer reaches 5 points, I want the gameover scene to display.

This is my score update function:

```
func addScore(playerWhoWon: SKSpriteNode) {
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    if playerWhoWon == main {

        score[0] += 1

        if score[0] >= 5 {
            // call a function that segues to endGame()
        }

        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.7
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            self.ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 15, dy: 15))
        }

    } else if playerWhoWon == enemy {

        score[1] += 1

        if score[1] >= 5 {
            // call a function that segues to endGame()
        }

        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.7
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            self.ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -15, dy: -15))
        }   
    }

    topLbl.text = "\(score[1])"
    btmLbl.text = "\(score[0])"
}
```

I want to be able to call the "endGame" function, which segues to a "You Win" or "You Lose" UIViewcontroller, depending on the outcome of the game. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your SKScene, declare a view controller

```
var viewController: UIViewController?
```

In your storyboard, create a segue between the view controller that is hosting your SKScene and your game over view controller. Give it an identifier.

Wherever you want to segue, call this (replacing "identifier" with your identifier):

```
viewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: viewController)
```

Comment: I declared the view controller, and created a segue between my SKScene VC and my youWinVC. I then posted the segue command in my youWin function, which shows a winning game over screen:                                 
func youWin() {
        self.ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        viewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "youWinSegue", sender: viewController)
    } // I tried to identify the segue itself and the youWin view controller, but either still did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try self.viewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: self.viewController) Also, make sure you're calling this function in your code.

Comment: I added the self prefix to the view controller but no effect. In my if score >=5 statement, I call the youWin function. It works because the physics adjustment line(in my previous comment above the segue command) stops the ball at the end of the game, it just doesn't segue to the new VC.

Comment: I think it has to do with the SKScene being attached to my GameVC, so I have to reference a segue stated in the GameVC from the SKScene in order to segue to the youWinVC. I'm just not sure how to reference the GameVC from inside the SKScene.

Comment: Have you set scene.viewController = self in your GameVC? You should be referencing the GameVC with the viewController variable.

Comment: I ended up changing my approach. I now have a new SKScene for the Game Over screen. When a score of 5 is reached, GameScene transitions to YouWinScene. On the YouWinScene, I prompt the user to tap the screen to return to menu. I then followed the instructions you gave me. I performed a segue to the MenuVC in the touchesBegan function within the YouWinScene.swift. Everything works except the app crashes when I tap the screen. Any idea to why this is? Thank you very much for your help so far!

Comment: This is my touchesBegan function, I'm not sure if this is correct, but this is where the app crashes. 'override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {                
        
        self.viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MenuSegue", sender: viewController)
        
    }'